# Why node.js does not have something like goroutines from Go?

Tags: node.js

I wonder why callback hell did not get some conceptual solution. Something like goroutines from Go, stackless python, eventlet, gevent, monkey patching or something like that. Is it possible to make it for javascript? Does anybody work on it? JavaScript is a great concise language but the callback hell is a major drawback.

Comment: goroutines are a different concept from callbacks. They're technically the equivalent to web workers in javascript. The reason why go avoids callback hell is that it communicates with goroutines using channels rather than callbacks. In this sense node already has a similar functionality - streams.

Comment: https://github.com/ubolonton/js-csp implements goroutines, https://github.com/visionmedia/co provides another implementation of generator-based flow control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because those are language features and Javascript doesn't have them.

I think there's talk about finally getting coroutines, but I don't know the details.

Comment: Coroutines and goroutines are different concepts. Javascript already has something similar to goroutines: web workers. Coroutines are more like continuations. But coroutines do have the potential to significantly reduce callback hell.

Comment: Check out http://npmjs.com/async-csp. It's really nice.